# Can I install multiple bots on a single Facebook fanpage

Tags: bots, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

We are having two teams building two bots for our Facebook fanpage. One is for customer service and the other one is for a quiz campaign. Can we have the two bots on the same fanpage? Will there be any conflicts such as the custom menu?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is YES!
However unless managed correctly there will be conflict.
I know it is possible to use one chatbot built on ManyChat and another on Flowxo. 
I need to ensure that I LIMIT the "keywords" in ManyChat so that ManyChat does not respond and allows FLOWXO to respond.

In my situation, I am using the Pro version of MC to get users subscribed and to further broadcast to them or subscribe them to a sequence. I pass over the conversation to Flowxo for integrations to third party software and for the basic conversational aspect of the chatbot.

Passing the conversation over from one chatbot to the other takes some manipulation of the use of keywords and Flowxo's "unrecognised phrase" flow. 
I will post the link to a blog post when I get around to writing about how I did it.

Another issue as you pointed out is the Greeting and Welcome text. I have not figured out a way to control this and as it turns out with my chatbot, users always appear to enter into the chatbot via ManyChat which fortunately for me is exactly what I need.

Comment: Hi Hilton, just wondering if you wrote that blog post? If yes, could you please share the link. Also, does this mean you use specific conversation flows to drive the user to talk to a specific bot out of the two bots integrated within one chat window?